# How can solve this error in nginx logs?

Tags: nginx, logging, errors

nginx version: nginx/1.6.2

```
/usr/logs/nginx-error.log [
    uest: "GET /server-status HTTP/1.1", host: "127.0.0.1"
    2015/03/14 05:21:24 [error] 23068#0: *8616047 openat() "/var/www/html/server-status" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 127.0.0.1, server: myname.proj, req
]
```

---

**My location is set:**

```
location /nginx_status {
    # Enable nginx status page
    stub_status off;

    # Disable status page logging in access_log
    access_log off;

    # Allow access from 127.0.0.1
    allow 127.0.0.1;

    # Deny all the other connections
    deny all;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want the requestor to be able to get some basic stats when requesting that url, add:

```
location /server-status {
    stub_status; 
}
```

to your configuration.  If you do not, you will need to find and stop whatever is making that request to eliminate the error.

Comment: But the problem is not solved